# Export HTML DataTable to Excel - Display URL to Image in Excel

Tags: html, jquery, excel, datatables, nunjucks

I'm trying to display an HTML DataTables URL to the actual image in an Excel column.

Right now, when I export the DataTable to Excel it populates the corresponding column with the URL itself, what I want to achieve is to actually populate the Excel column with the Image, not the Image URL.

Right now, I can see the image for the comment.screenshot variable into HTML, but in Excel, it is blank, while for the rest of comment.screenshot1,comment.screenshot2 and comment.screenshot3, only the URL is populated in Excel.

**jQuery**:

```
$("#tableComments").DataTable({
            stripHtml: !1,
            dom: "Bfrtip",
            buttons: ["copyHtml5", "excelHtml5", "csvHtml5", "pdfHtml5"]
        })
```

**HTML**:

```
<table id="tableComments" class="display table table-info table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>User</th>
                                <th>Version</th>
                                <th>Round</th>
                                <th>Comment</th>
                                <th>Screenshot #1</th>
                                <th>Screenshot #2</th>
                                <th>Screenshot #3</th>
                                <th>Screenshot #4</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for comment in comments %}
                            <tr>
                                
                                    <td>{{ comment.user.username }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ comment.versionName }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ comment.round }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ comment.comment }}</td>
                                    <td><img src="{{ comment.screenshot }}" /></td>
                                    <td>{{ comment.screenshot1 }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ comment.screenshot2 }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ comment.screenshot3 }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ comment.approved }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
```

I highly appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41096/export-image-in-printing)? They say it won't strip html.

Comment: When I do that, it populates the screenshot column in Excel with <img src="URL" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Datatables export buttons you may use a different approach using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

The snippet:

```js
$("#tableComments").DataTable({
  stripHtml: !1,
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: ['copyHtml5', 'csvHtml5', 'pdfHtml5']
})
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent( document.getElementById('tableComments').outerHTML));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

<button>Export To Excel</button>
<table id="tableComments" class="display table table-info table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Version</th>
        <th>Round</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>Screenshot #1</th>
        <th>Screenshot #2</th>
        <th>Screenshot #3</th>
        <th>Screenshot #4</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>

        <td>username1</td>
        <td>versionName</td>
        <td>round</td>
        <td>comment </td>
        <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=1"/></td>
        <td>screenshot1</td>
        <td>screenshot2</td>
        <td>screenshot3</td>
        <td>approved</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>username2</td>
        <td>versionName</td>
        <td>round</td>
        <td>comment </td>
        <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=2"/></td>
        <td>screenshot1</td>
        <td>screenshot2</td>
        <td>screenshot3</td>
        <td>approved</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>username3</td>
        <td>versionName</td>
        <td>round</td>
        <td>comment </td>
        <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=3"/></td>
        <td>screenshot1</td>
        <td>screenshot2</td>
        <td>screenshot3</td>
        <td>approved</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work, however I encountered 3 issues. Firstly, I receive this error message after opening the file in Excel: https://prnt.sc/xflc85. Secondly, the file name is no longer the page name, it's download.xls. Is there any simple way to change it to the page name? Lastly, the images in the Excel have their actual size, overlapping the other columns: https://prnt.sc/xfli41. Is there any way to make them wrap/fit into their corresponding column, in this case, the screenshot column? Thank you!